# The Daimler advert is way more than 300px wide and overflows out of the side bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, sidebar

Every other advert is 300px wide and fits nicely in the side bar, e.g.:

> [image: normal side bar]

The image used in the Daimler advert is 728px wide:

> [image: Daimler ad image]

This causes it to overflow out of the side bar, necessitating a horizontal scroll bar on my (1920px wide) monitor:

> [image: very wide image]

Is this expected?

This is on Firefox 69.0.1, if that's relevant.

Comment: That seems like a perfectly cromulent ad. The product is very cunningly targeted to users with "ultra" wide screens.

Comment: I didn't expect the ad to require me to embiggen my screen though.

Comment: It is an extended Daimler ...

Comment: @yivi Be honest, all you were looking for was an opportunity, any opportunity, to make use of the word "cromulent"

Comment: Logically, @Magisch. But I'm always looking for new opportunities. This one seemed apropos.

Comment: Also experienced that ad on [chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E23Bo.png), so Firefox doesn't appear to be relevant

Comment: To be fair, the 728px-wide hints at ["leaderboard" style ad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) that SO (and SE) also uses. So the problem might not be the size, but the location...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I work in the Ad Ops team. Thanks for the heads up - this creative was trafficked incorrectly and has been updated.